# writing a conditional insert statement

Tags: mysql

```
update A set x = '0' where [condition];
```

if the where-condition isn't fulfilled no update takes place.

depending on this I want to trigger an insert in another table, but only if an update was done - i.e. ROW_COUNT() > 0.

how may I do that in one request?

I tried this:

```
update A set x = '0' where [condition];

if row_count() > 0 then

  insert into [...];

end if;
```

this leads to an error.

PS:

The question is purely aming at a possibility to to execute an update and a conditional insert in one db-request. SQL-Injection-safty is assured by using prepared statements.

Comment: Could you post complete code?

Comment: no. the code is sufficient. my question is specifically about how to write a query with a conditional statement.

Comment: which version of mysql are you using. Also, what is the error? Do you get the same error if you run- select row_count()?

Comment: select row_count() is fine. row_count is an inbuilt mysql-function BTW. it's a syntax error and I use the most recent version.

Comment: @Raffael1984: in that case, post the complete syntax error.

Comment: @Mat: best answer so far here, OP question is really not acceptable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a stored procedure like:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE updateA (c1 varchar)
BEGIN
  declare rows_affected integer;

  UPDATE a SET x = '0' WHERE col1 = c1;

  SELECT row_count() INTO rows_affected;

  IF rows_affected > 0 THEN BEGIN
    INSERT INTO .....
  END; END IF;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Or use an AFTER UPDATE trigger

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER au_a_each AFTER UPDATE ON a FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO b (x,a_id) VALUES (new.x, new.id);
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: (+1 of course). thanks for the SP but triggers won't do the trick for two reasons. a trigger is invoked if the update was succesful. though my update will alway be succesful as in not leading to an error. i need a different criteria for the insert. also i need to insert the users IP which is not accessible for the trigger.

Comment: @Raffael, If the `where` clause is not true, the update trigger does not get called.

Comment: really ... oh that's interesting. I'll check that!

Answer (score 0):

you can do it two sql statements, as long as your condition is mutually exclusive, i.e. if it "allows" an update, then it will by definition exclude an insert, and vice-versa.

e.g.

```
UPDATE your_table set col1 = 'x'
where condition = <some condition here>
;

INSERT your_table (col1)  
select x from some_other_table where condition = <some condition here>
;
```